# VueJS/VueX Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm currently working on a Vue project, I'm using Vuex for state management. But when I bind the two actions below in my component with mapactions and mapgetters I get **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error in my console.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

[image: Screenshot of error]

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import service from "../services/statisticsService"
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
    customersAndServicesOverTime:[],
    counters:{}
}
const actions = {
    actGetAllData(context){
        context.dispatch('actGetCustomersAndServicesOverTime')
        context.dispatch('actGetCounters')
    },

    actGetCustomersAndServicesOverTime(context){
        service.getCustomerAndServicesOverTime(context.getters.getJWT)
            .then(response =>{
                context.commit('mutCustomersAndServicesOverTime', response.body)
            })
    },
    actGetCounters(context){
        service.getCounts(context.getters.getJWT)
            .then(response =>{
                context.commit('mutCounts', response.body)
            })
    }
}
const mutations = {
    mutCustomersAndServicesOverTime(state,payload){
        state.customersAndServicesOverTime ={
            labels:payload.map(x => moment(x.created).format("DD-MM-YYYY")),
            datasets:[{
                data:payload.map(x => x.customersCount), 
                backgroundColor:"rgba(52, 73, 94,0.5)", 
                label:"customers",lineTension:0
            },{
                data:payload.map(x => x.servicesCount),
                backgroundColor:"rgba(230, 126, 34,0.5)", 
                label:"services",lineTension:0
            }]}
    },
    mutCounts(state,payload){
        state.counters = payload
    },
}
const getters = {
    getCustomersAndServicesOverTime:state=>state.customersAndServicesOverTime,
    getCounts:state=>state.counters,
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

In my service I declared Two function that connect with my API.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import CONFIG from "../config"

export default {
    getCounts(jwt) {
        return Vue.http.get(CONFIG.API + "statistics/counts", {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                ,'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
            }
        })
    },
    getCustomerAndServicesOverTime(jwt) {
        return Vue.http.get(CONFIG.API + "statistics/customersandservicesovertime", {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                ,'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: it is more likely you are calling something from within itself. So, infinite loop will cause that message. Check your code for infinite loops, references

Comment: That's what I read everywhere. But can't find where... I already rewrote everything in my store...

Comment: click on the file in red, maybe it will show you the source line of the error

Comment: Could it be that I get this error from the .map?

Comment: It wasn't a vuex problem... In my getters I needed a deep copy... thanks for the help

Comment: wow, I would've never figured that out. glad you found it

Comment: @ivancoene can you show to us what deep copy mean? I have similar error like you. Thanks

Comment: @hendra1 Check here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't a vuex problem. I use vue-chartjs and I didn't hard copy my object instance but used it as a reference. Which causes the Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/197